# Does the `Dictionary` created by the default constructor use a hash code?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I need to use a class that I have written as the type of the key for a `Dictionary`

I read the [documentation on MSDN about the default constructor of `Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90.aspx)

> `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` requires an equality implementation to
>   determine whether keys are equal. This constructor uses the default
>   generic equality comparer, `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. If type
>   `TKey` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the
>   default equality comparer uses that implementation. Alternatively, you
>   can specify an implementation of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` generic
>   interface by using a constructor that accepts a comparer parameter.

This makes think that the only thing I have to do is to have my class for the key implement `System.IEquatable<T>`

However i'm very surprised that [`System.IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) doesn't have a `HashCode()` method.

So will the Dictionary created this way use a hash code? If yes where does it come from ? Otherwise, will my Dictionary have constant cost access operations (I don't think it's achievable without a hash code)

Comment: I believe that the c# dictionary actually does use hashing

Comment: Also read the "Remarks" section of your second link, the `IEquatable<>` interface. It says: _If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you should also override the base class implementations of `Object.Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method. If you do override `Object.Equals(Object)`, your overridden implementation is also called in calls to the static `Equals(System.Object, System.Object)` method on your class. This ensures that all invocations of the `Equals` method return consistent results._

Comment: Yeah I noticed that on 2nd read after seeing Babak Naffas's answer. Actually i'm new to `.Net` and seeing `Equals` method in `IEquatable`, and `Equals + GetHashCode` in `IEqualityComparer` lead me to think that `Equals` and `GetHashCode` were not in the `Object` class in `.Net` (without checking, my bad). I did not think about the subtlety of the performance issue highlighted by luksan's answer which justifies an alternate method with a generic parameter, hence a generic interface to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still uses the overridden `object.GetHashCode()` method to obtain the hash code. The reason that there is a separate `IEquatable<T>` interface (i.e. why the default `EqualityComparer<T>` doesn't always just call the overridden `object.Equals()` method to compare two objects) is for performance reasons - `object.Equals()` takes an `object` argument and therefore the implementation has to cast it to the target type before it can perform a meaningful comparison (value types also have to be boxed and unboxed); whereas the argument to `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` is already of type `T`. This performance consideration doesn't apply to the `GetHashCode()` method since it takes no argument, hence there is no reason for it to exist on the `IEquatable<T>` interface.

Answer (score 4):

> However i'm very surprised that System.IEquatable doesn't have a HashCode() method.

It would be redundant for `System.IEquatable<T>` to have a HashCode method as [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) (which your implementing class will implicitly inherit from) already provides the method [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dictionary will use a hash code. The dictionary is really a hash map beneath the covers.

The hash code implementation it will use is the one implemented by `GetHashCode` in your key. If you do not define an implementation yourself, the hash code will be based on reference for reference types, and on the individual fields for value types (structs). When using your own class as the key in a dictionary, it is advised to implement `GetHashCode`.

When you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you must override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on object to match your implementation of `IEquatable<T>`. The reason why it is not in the interface, is that `GetHashCode` is already defined on `object`, that all classes derive from, so having it in the interface would not make a difference.

If you fail to implement `GetHashCode` so it matches your `IEquatable<T>` implementation, you might run into an issue where you put a key in a dictionary, but are unable to retrieve it again, because the hash code does not match: When the dictionary looks for a key, it first calls `GetHashCode` on that key. From this, the dictionary derives the internal `bucket`, that the key should be in. Then it looks through all keys in that particular bucket and calls `Equals` to find the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary (HashSet and KeyedCollections) all use HashBuckets (for speed).
HashBuckets use GetHashCode which is Int32.

If objects are not equal then they must have different GetHashCode.
But two objects that are not equal may have the same GetHashCode.

If the GetHashCode is the same then the tie breaker is Equals.
GetHashCode comparison is faster - you want to avoid the tie breaker.

You want a good (unique) GetHashCode.
If the objects come from a database and the table has key and that key is Int32 (or less) then use that for a perfect hash code.

If your objects don't have a natural key then can use the system GetHashCode.
But if you have a natural key then use it.

All object implement Object 
[Object Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)
If your class does not overrite GetHashCode then it will come from Object.

Advise against Tuple or KeyValuePair for Key as they don't produce a good GetHashCode.    Lot of collisions.